# App Engine Gen 2 Go 1.12 - timeouts since migrated from Go 1.9 Gen1

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Last week i migrated from GO 1.9 to GO 1.12. Since then i get random timeouts. With the following message:

> Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. Please
>   ensure that your HTTP server is listening for requests on 0.0.0.0 and
>   on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. (Error code 123)

Since the timeouts are seemingly random and most of the time its working, i would guess the server is correct configured....
Warmup is configured and a quick look in the logs suggest that its working fine.

I have no idea what to look for, maybe someone had similar issues?

EDIT: Here some logs (all for the same request) - clone-id's simplified -

> - 16:36:17 - 200 after 1s (New process) - clone-id: 1
> - 8x 16:41:07:xx - 502 after 604,7s (terminated - timeout) - clone-id:1
> - 16:42 - 200 after 1,9s (New process) - clone-id: 2
> - 16:42 - 200 after 2,1 (New process) - clone-id: 3
> - 2x 16:50 - 502 after 24s (terminated - timeout) - clone-id: 1
> - 3x 17:12:39 - 200 after 2,6s (New process) - clone-id: 4, 5, 6
> - 4x 18:21:16 - 502 after 604,9s (terminated - timeout) - clone-id: 4

EDIT 2: I use a Cloud SQL client, Datastore client and Storage client. I initialize them just once at the startup. Is this a mistake?

EDIT 3: I can replicate the issue now... it seems to be a problem when the client doesn't send any header information. The requests wont even reach the GO Application. When i use a small node-js app with "request-promise" to fire a bunch of requests it will die. Everytime.

app.yaml:

```
runtime: go112
env: standard
instance_class: F2
inbound_services:
  - warmup
handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto
```

Comment: The different runtime most likely has different timings, it's possible the migration simply brought your app overall closer to the deadline limit and the occasional spikes now cross that. Try to determine from the logs if the response times have all increased more or less proportionally, or just those of the odd peaks (i.e. if it's an overall increase or just some corner case-related one). With that info you could determine where you should focus your investigation.

Comment: The different runtime acutally has decreased the overall response times. I have a public API endpoint where the average response time is 2.6sec and sometimes it just dies after 600sec. In general are 99.9% of all responses far far away from the deadline. Its really just random...

Comment: OK, so it's a corner case. Try to see if there's a pattern to those failures. Maybe same request path/handlers? If not maybe some common ops to all handlers for those requests? Maybe grouped close to instance (re)starts? Any traceback hints in the logs?

Comment: The only pattern i can recognize is that it happends after the system had time to idle for 5+ minutes.

Comment: Does it happen when a new process is started (the logs show message *This request caused a new process to be started for your application...*)?

Comment: I added some logs to my post. Here should be noted that it is filtered by the same request there are other requests in between. Its happens but it is not really a "pattern".

Comment: I use a Cloud SQL client, Datastore client and Storage client. I initialize them just once at the startup. Is this a mistake?

Comment: hey @Tiega, can provide me with this information: App Engine environment, error reporting (tracebacks) and one of your timeout error logs expanded from the Logging? I don't think initializing Cloud SQL client, Datastore client and Storage client once at the startup is a mistake and don't have to do with this issue.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi there are no traces, the request comes and dies. I noticed that the requests not even reach the GO application. It dies within the nginx.... I also noticed that it always happens with the same client. The client doesn't send any header infos. I can even replicate the issue now, maybe this caueses problems in the nginx?

Comment: Try to implement [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/configuring-warmup-requests) in your application. let me know if that solves your issue, so I can post it as a solution.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi i already had. Like i sad i look like the request doesn't even reach my running Go-App, it seems do timeout before.

Comment: Can you post your app.yaml file? also explain the use case and the structure of your application?

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi app.yaml added, its just basic. The Application is a ERP System. What you mean with Structure? Its an API-First and Controller-Repo-Model based system.

Comment: @Tiega, what do you mean in your previous comment by "same client"?

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi One of my users accessed a API via "request-promise" without any header. I contacted the user and ask to change it. Since then everything is stable. Seems to be a bug within the App Engine routing. I will try in a different Project later.

Comment: Please, let me know if this issue occurs again and if you have a support package, don't hesitate to contact us and [create a case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case). This will help us to have more visibility and troubleshoot your issue faster.